# Inserting a node at the tail of a linked list code

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to solve the data structure problems on hackerrank. I just can't seem to find what is wrong with my code. I would like to know if there's something wrong here.

```
Node* Insert(Node *head,int data){
struct Node *ptr = head,*new_node=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

new_node->data=data;
new_node->next=NULL;
if(ptr){
    while(ptr->next != NULL){
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    ptr->next=new_node;
}
else{
    head=new_node;
}
return(head);
}
```

Strangely, the same code was accepted few months back when I was practising. Here's the [link to the problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insert-a-node-at-the-tail-of-a-linked-list/problem).

P.S. I have spent hours trying to figure out, and I'm not sure if SO is an appropriate place to ask the question. If it isn't, I'm willing to remove it.

Edit :

```
Node is defined as 

  struct Node
  {
     int data;
     struct Node *next;
  }
```

Comment: Programs for online judge or competition sites are usually hard to impossible to debug since they don't normally tell you the input to your program. Without knowing the actual input, all you could ask for is a review of your whole program and tell us what the judging site tells you (which you haven't done). Also, such sites are really no good for learning anything except how to write program for such sites. Get a few books, go to classes, take online courses, it will all be better ways for beginners for actual learning.

Comment: the problem is, all they say is 'wrong output' and that is it. I'll be satisfied as long as there isn't any glaring logical error. May be something's wrong with the site..errr. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: BTW: you are mixing `struct Node` and `Node`. (are you using a C++ compiler, by any chance?)

Comment: @wildplasser they don't provide a C compiler, so yes a C++ one. Could that be a problem?

Comment: I just tried it, and I ended up with a problem as well. "Your Output (stdout): Right Answer! ... Expected Output: <list of numbers>" The instructions specifically say to not read anything from stdin and not print anything to stdout, so I think there's a problem with the exercise.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune I tried a few other problems that I had previously solved but this time nothing got accepted, so I thought probably I'm doing something wrong. Thanks for trying it out!

Comment: @momo Even I think something's wrong in the test cases, because I looked at my submission I made 2 years ago and it's not passing now.

Comment: such a relief. Thank you to all!

Comment: After viewing the discussion section, it seems that more people lately are having problems, one even finding that [the leaderboard's correct answer in Python 3 is no longer accepted](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insert-a-node-at-the-tail-of-a-linked-list/forum/comments/439412). I also thought it might be due to a browser extension I had installed, so I temporarily disabled it, but I was met with failure once more. It's definitely not just you!

Comment: wow someone needs to notify these guys. It was a nice way to get some practise.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `typedef` the structure to avoid naming mismatch.

```
struct node {
     int data;
     struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node Node;
```

`Insert()` function should be

```
void Insert(Node **head,int data){
        while(*head){
                head = &(*head)->next;
        }
        *head = malloc(sizeof **head);
        (*head)->data=data;
        (*head)->next=NULL;
}
```

And call `Insert()` like this

```
int main() {
        Node *headptr = 0;
        Insert(&headptr, 100);/*pass the address of headptr */
        /*.. 
        display(headptr); 
        */
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but it's still not working, and if I remove the casting, it throws an error for that too.

Comment: @momo can you provide struct `Node` definition and how you are calling `Insert()` . you can edit your question

Comment: @momo I modified my answer.

Comment: thank you! It probably would have solved the problem but as it seems, something is probably wrong with this hackerrank problem. Also, they don't let us see how the function is being called. Thank you much though!

Comment: If you use the pointer-to-pointer construct, you don't need an extra (*head==NULL) condition, just the loop.

Comment: very first time when `ptr` is `0` then It needs to update `*head` so `else` condition is required. correct me if I am wrong @wildplasser

Comment: No, you dont need the dereference into ptr. (you dont need ptr at all) like: `void Insert(Node **head,int data){ 

        while(*head){ head = &(*head)->next;}

        *head = malloc(sizeof **head);
        (*head)->data=data; 
        (*head)->next=NULL;
}`

Comment: Thanks @wildplasser your version of answer is short & simple.

Answer (score -1):

I think your code is incorrect, due to misunderstanding of how pointers are passed by value, in your case if list is empty you will do:

```
head=new_node;
```

But this will assign new node not to head but to some temporary head pointer copy (head), your real head is still null, so you have to pass pointer to pointer to head:

```
Node* Insert(Node **head,int data)
```

and assign:

```
*head = new_node;
```